# Let X be a set with subsets A and B. Prove X\(A\B) = B U (X\A)

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set with subsets $A$ and $B$. Prove

$$X\setminus(A\setminus B) = B\cup (X\setminus A).$$

I know that in order to prove equality, I must show the left side is a subset of the right, and the right is a subset of the left. Do I let an arbitrary element belong to the left side and show it is also in the right side? And vice versa?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it's done.

Comment: Yes, that is the most straightforward way.   Just use the definitions and see what comes.

Comment: You may possibly be able to show, through equivalences, or "if and only if" statements, that the proof is bidirection.

Comment: I was too quick in posting my erroneous answer (didn't see the part about $A$ and $B$ being *subsets* of $X$); anyhow, hopefully my answer now illustrates what I wanted to communicate, namely that I would avoid element-chasing proofs whenever possible and use basic set algebra instead. Of course, if you are being *required* to use an element-chasing proof...then there's not much else to do I suppose!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is generally how you would go about such a problem (a so-called "element-chasing proof"), but I would encourage you to go about these problems in an [*algebraic* way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1478949/191378) whenever possible (it's *much* more efficient, as the linked to example shows):
\begin{align*}
B\cup(X\setminus A)
&=B\cup(X\cap A^c) & \text{(by definition)}\\[0.5em]
&= (B\cup X)\cap(B\cup A^c) & \text{(distributivity)}\\[0.5em]
&= X\cap(B\cup A^c) & \text{(since $B\subseteq X$)}\\[0.5em]
&= X\cap(A\cap B^c)^c & \text{(DeMorgan)}\\[0.5em]
&=X\setminus(A\setminus B)
\end{align*}